# Does anyone know what insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

[image]

Living in Brasília, central Brazil; currently experiencing rainy warm/hot days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it's a female Pelecinid parasitic wasp (see [this page](https://bugguide.net/node/view/6943) for an overview of the family in the western hemisphere); from your location the species is either *Pelecinus polyturator* or *Pelecinus dichrous* (all of BugGuide's images are of the former, that being the one also found in the United States).